# MVC Scaffolded view - Disable google default date picker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, google-chrome

I have scaffolded some view with MVC, and used a jquery datepicker dropdown which matches the colour my scheme. This works fine in Internet Explorer, but when testing with chrome, I get a second date dropdown over the top of my dropdown - which I assume is the default chrome date picker. Is there anyway of disabling the default chrome date picker?

---

[image]

Chrome - 2 date pickers

---

[image]

IE - Just the 1 pate picker

Comment: Your most likely using `EditorFor()` on a `DateTime` property that is decorated with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` which generates the HTML5 implementation your browsers datepicker. Change it to use `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: Changing it to a TextBoxFor stops both of the dropdowns working, and really throws the layout out

Comment: Then remove the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute from the property

Answer (score 0):

Model (any format should work, but cooperate with datepicker):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

View (very important: type = "text"):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Published, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" } })
```